# Data version control (DVC) edit files in place results in cyclic dependency

Tags: dvc

we have a larger dataset and have several preprocessing scripts.
These scripts alter data in place.
It seems when I try to register it with `dvc run` it complains about cyclic dependencies (input is the same as output).
I would assume this is a very common use case.

What is the best practice here ?

Tried to google around but i did not see any solution to this (besides creating another folder for the output).

Comment: for the record, discussion is happening here https://discuss.dvc.org/t/processing-data-in-place/361

Comment: I'll try to summarize and put together an answer after it's done

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we split input and output into separate files rather than modify everything in place, not only for the separation of concerns principles but also to make it fit with tools like DVC.

Hope you can try this way instead.